# macos terminal with sudo cannot find hidden file

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, sudo, macos-bigsur

Im executing the command in mac terminal

sudo /Users/username/someFolder/programForMacOs

programForMacOs runs and looks for a file in the same directory its running from (/Users/username/someFolder/) with name .programForMacOsNeedsMe

However, it gives me an error

Err:/Users/username/someFolder/.programForMacOsNeedsMe: no such file or directory

In Finder i can see  the file /Users/username/someFolder/.programForMacOsNeedsMe exists but is a hidden file.

How can I make the file available to programForMacOs ?

Comment: anything with a dot at the head of the name is a hidden file. Can you use the actual names, because the use of anything called .exe on Mac is puzzling. What kind of app is this?

Comment: I updated to remove any references to exe.

Comment: It's very non-standard behaviour for a Mac app to be dependant on a separate file in a relative location. Without knowing specifics, all I could say is contact the developer.

Comment: @Tetsujin I was able to get it to work by putting the file in my root folder.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello there, Hober Malloy**

Why don't you start by listing all of the items in the folder you are trying to access...

```
cd /Users/username/someFolder
```

And then...

```
ls -a
```

After that you should firstly consider making that item visible by using...

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
```

Or by executing the file when you see it listed by running...

```
sudo .programForMacOsNeedsMe
```

**I hope this helps :)**